# How do I run start script when deploying nuxt 3 app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've been trying to deploy a Nuxt 3 app that requires a Node.js instance to Heroku.

I've added Procfile to the root of my project, but the documentation, which I think is referencing Nuxt 2, says to add the script command 'yarn start' to get a node.js instance up and running on the server.

However, Nuxt 3 does not have a start command.

What command do I add to the Procfile for a Nuxt 3 app? Or is this no longer necessary?

Answer (score 7):

And of course I found an answer as soon as I posted this.

Add "start": "node .output/server/index.mjs" to your package.json.

Then you can add 'web: yarn start' or 'web:npm run start' to your Procfile.

[Source from the Nitro documentation.](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/heroku)